# left outer join needed on jpa / hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two tables

```
Parent
id| guid | value1

Child
id| parentguid| childguid | value2

foreign key Child(parentguid) references Parent(guid)
foreign key Child(childguid) references Parent(guid)
```

i need a left outer join

```
select p.id, p.guid , p.value1 , c.parentguid, c.value2 from Parent p left outer join Child c on p.guid = c.childguid;
```

how can I write the hibernate / jpa entity which gives me such.

```
class Parent{
Long id;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn("guid")
Child guid;

String value1;
}

class Child{
Long id;

String parentguid;

String childguid;

String value2;
}
```

Typesafe queries don't provide left outer join -> http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-typesafejpa/

Comment: a left outer join where ? in a query ? in which case JPQL ? Criteria? what?

Comment: can you differentiate the 2 foreign keys you have: childguid and parentguid? if this is one-to-one relationship, a single foreign key should be sufficient (unless you have composite keys from your parent entity)

Comment: Clearly Criteria queries do provide LEFT OUTER JOIN, via the join method passing in a JoinType. Your question makes no sense, so I suggest you rework it

Comment: @NeilStockton I want to know if by annotation as above like OneToOne  based on Join column can I do a left outer join? Not intending JPQL. This is useful that I get a combined Parent Entity.

Comment: @Ish there is a one to one relation between guid and childguid. a parent guid null signifies absence of child entity OR to say in another terms no right side entity , only left side.

Comment: If you mean to simply retrieve the 1-1 field of the owning object, "you" don't do anything. The JPA implementation decides. Some JPA implementations will look at the "optional" attribute and use that to decide whether to do INNER or LEFT OUTER.